# Laravel PHP array Eloquent

Tags: arrays, laravel, controller, eloquent

I have this in my controller

```
   $lista = Lesson::where('id', $id_less)
                ->with(['user' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('users.id', Auth::user()->id);
                }])
                ->get();
```

output is :

```
[{"id":2,"id_lessontype":"1","name":"Second lesson","text":"","url1":"","url2":"","created_at":"2015-10-22 03:27:14","updated_at":"2015-10-22 03:27:14","user":[{"status":"Complete","id":2,"name":"licki","email":"licki32@hotmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-22 12:41:49","updated_at":"2015-10-22 12:41:49","pivot":{"lesson_id":2,"user_id":2,"status_id":1}}]}]
```

How i can only display **status** of this array?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
   $lista = Lesson::where('id', $id_less)
                ->with(['user' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('users.id', Auth::user()->id);
                }])
                ->first()
                ->user
                ->status;
```

or

```
$lista = Lesson::find($id_less)
             ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'lesson.id')
             ->where('users.id', Auth::user()->id)
             ->pluck('status');
```